# running windows exe file using spawn in nodejs

Tags: node.js, spawn

in my nodejs project, iam trying to run .exe file of cpp code which is generated manually and store at a location. I have given the command just as how we run the .exe file manually in the command of spawn, but iam getting the error

```
"error": "program ended with exit code 1, '.\\problemID1.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\noperable program or batch file.\r\n"
```

```
export const expectedOutput = (problemID, input) => {
  const jobId = `problemID${problemID}`;
  console.log("this is the expected output path ",expectedOutputPath);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    //the code present here looks redundant, so have to do something to remove this
    let output = "";
    const command = `cd "${expectedOutputPath}" && .\\${jobId}.exe`;
    const process = spawn("cmd", ["/s", "/c", command], { shell: true });
    process.stdin.write(input);
    process.stdin.end();
    process.stdout.on("data", (data) => {
      console.log("here at stdout");
      output += data.toString();
    });
    process.stderr.on("data", (data) => {
      console.log("here at stderr", data);
      output += data.toString();
    });
    process.on("close", (code) => {
      if (code === 0) {
        resolve(output);
      } else {
        console.log(output, typeof output);
        reject(
          `program ended with exit code ${code}, ${output.error || output}`
        );
      }
    });
  });
};
```

this is the code for the method where iam getting error